# Elevation overlay for a standard BottomSheet

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-dark-theme

I'm following the material3 spec, using the *android material components* lib, and implementing light and dark themes.

I have a ConstraintLayout acting as a BottomSheet, and its background color should be affected by the [elevation overlay](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles#0abbf8b7-61e1-49ee-9f97-4967beb1e4fe) tint. BottomSheets are on [the list](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark) of material components implementing elevation overlay, but mine is keeping its default color, colorSurface, instead of becoming lighter in dark mode :

[image: Screenshot]
(The color doesn't change when the BottomSheet is expanded.)

The only thing that defines my ConstraintLayout as a BottomSheet is the `layout_behaviour` attribute, and I'm wondering how this could actually impact background color. Are BottomSheets only present on the previous list for their *modal* variant ?

If so, how would one implement the elevation overlay on a whole ConstraintLayout ? Through an `ElevationOverlayProvider`, as suggested by the second page linked above ?

---

Here is the simplified layout of my main Activity :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            .../>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        ... />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/band_list_bottomsheet"
        layout="@layout/bottomsheet_filter_and_sort"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the included BottomSheet layout (again, simplified) :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorSurface">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/title_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pill"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bottomsheet_dragable_pill"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/TextStyle.BottomSheetTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/filterandsort_sheet_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pill" />

    <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
        android:id="@+id/divider_title_filter"
        style="@style/HorizontalDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/filter_title"
        style="@style/TextStyle.BottomSheetSubheader"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider_title_filter"/>
        
    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried a few things on the the ConstraintLayout to trigger the elevation overlay, notably :

- Increase its elevation
- Force its style as the standard BottomSheet style `style="?attr/bottomSheetStyle"`

Initially, the ConstaintLayout had no background set, whereas the `title_background` view had one, a drawable used to display "Google Maps-style" rounded corners at the top of the BottomSheet.

My themes come from the [Material Theme Builder](https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/), so they extend `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` and `Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar`. As visible above, I'm using system attributes everywhere I can to keep the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the material-components-android library's BottomSheetBehaviour isn't meant to handle the elevation overlay, here's how to apply it to a Layout.

Extend the corresponding layout as follows :

```
class ElevationOverlayConstraintLayout(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attributes) {

    init {
        background = MaterialShapeDrawable.createWithElevationOverlay(context, elevation)
    }

    override fun setElevation(elevation: Float) {
        super.setElevation(elevation)

        MaterialShapeUtils.setElevation(this, elevation)
    }
}
```

Simply switch the original layout by this class in your xml layout definition, and *voila*, the elevation overlay is applied !

Sources : the dark theme [documentation page](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark) referenced in the question, and [this post](https://arturdryomov.dev/posts/midnight-in-android-themes/).

---

Bonus : for rounded corners at the top of the BottomSheet, change the init method as follows, and define the corner radius (e.g. 8dp) in your dimensions.

```
    init {
        val model = ShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.bottomsheet_corner_radius))
                .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.bottomsheet_corner_radius))
                .build()

        val shape = MaterialShapeDrawable.createWithElevationOverlay(context, elevation)
        shape.shapeAppearanceModel = model

        background = shape
    }
```